# Computing parallel line in CGAL

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

Does anybody know how to compute a Line_2 parallel to another Line_2(known) with a distance of "d" between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem creating a Line_2(a1, b1, c1) with the same a1 and b1 of the parallel line and a coefficient c1 equal to c + d*b.

Comment: This is incorrect. Try with a line perpendicular to x axis such as x = 0. It should be c+sqrt(a^ + b^2) d